# Why does this not pauseFx before morph-ing?

Tags: javascript, mootools

This morphs just fine but I need it to pause first then morph.

```
var animate = (function(){
    var div = document.getElement('div.es-transition');
    if (div){
        div.set('morph', {duration: 800, transition: 'quad:out'});
        div.pauseFx(1000, 'morph');
        div.addClass('hidden');
        div.setStyles({'visibility': 'hidden', 'opacity': 0});
        div.removeClass('hidden').fade('in');
    }
});

window.addEvent('load', animate);
```

Banging head.

TIA

Comment: Part of mootools-more [http://mootools.net/docs/more/Class/Chain.Wait#Element:pauseFx](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Class/Chain.Wait#Element:pauseFx) I started off using tween and got no joy. I just need to pause for one second then fade in.

Comment: that only sets link: chain and utilises fx.pause, wait and fx.resume, prolly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't know about `pauseFx`? this is not standard mootools-core api. it has http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx#Fx:pause - which needs to be applied to the instance.

in your case, it makes no sense anyway as you pause before you even run it. which means, use `setTimeout` or `delay`. `pause` is to stop and resume a morph/tween midway. please clarify what you are trying to achieve

also. `.set('morph')` does not work with `.fade()` - fade is based on `tween` options, not `morph`. the difference between tween and morph is single property vs multiple properties.

if I understand this correctly, you need to rewrite as:

```
var animate = (function(){
    var div = document.getElement('div.es-transition');
    if (div){
        div.set('tween', {duration: 800, transition: 'quad:out'});

        div.addClass('hidden');
        div.setStyles({'visibility': 'hidden', 'opacity': 0});

        (function(){
            div.removeClass('hidden').fade(0, 1);
        }).delay(1000);
    }
});

window.addEvent('load', animate);
```

Comment: Superb! That is exactly what I need! TYVM!